Booting from Cortex-M33 on STM32MP2
We have a significant portion of our application written with STMCubeIDE and running on a Cortex-M4.
We would like to migrate to an STM32MP2 microprocessor, which features A35 and M33 cores. However, our application requires that we can boot from the M33 part.
Is this possible? On STM's website, I have only found the boot procedure for the A35 part.

You probably need to look at section 5 in the Getting Started with STM32MP25x MPUs App Note.

The provided information demonstrates the process of booting from the M33 microcontroller, which is helpful. However, it lacks a detailed explanation of the boot chain mechanism and doesn't provide instructions on modifying the configuration to control the power-up sequence of the A35 processor.
